# How to set rsp in gdb?

Tags: gdb

I was trying to set rsp so that I can see call stack from it:

```
(gdb) set $rsp = 0x3fa4fefde930
Left operand of assignment is not an lvalue.
```

This is weird because I think the rsp should be able to set.

Is there anything that might cause this, and how to avoid it?

Comment: You should definitely be able to set `$rsp`. Does this happen with a small test binary (hello world)? Are you trying to set $rsp on a breakpoint, or are you examining a core dump?

Comment: And your binary is 64 bit?

Comment: I am debugging Chromium code, which is relatively big comparing to hello world. And my binary is 64 bit.

Comment: And this is relative to Native Client, so maybe the stack in gdb is modified.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are trying to set `$rsp` from other than the top-most frame? Try to switch to frame 0 first:

```
(gdb) select-frame 0
(gdb) set $rsp = 0x3fa4fefde930
```